# Is there any built in function in javascript/jquery to filter email like php's function (!filter_var($variablePassed, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
// check if e-mail address is well-formed
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
}
```

This code is filtering the email provided by the user.

My question is is there any built in function in javascript/jquery like this php built in function. Regex is doing it but some times regex stop working.I do not know why.
My question is not so good but my mind force me to ask so i can feel good.I cannot sleep without answer.

Comment: no there isn't, you need a regex for it

Comment: why not just use ajax for this while using the serverside validation? That way you get the best of both worlds.

Comment: :D well that is a nice idea thanks for that idea.It was not clicked in my mind

Comment: *"Regex is doing it but some times regex stop working"* - You should show us the regex you're using and the HTML for it. There might be something in there that some browsers don't like.

Comment: That's true but one more thing that you said use ajax for this while using the server side validation.But i was thinking that suppose user has disable the javascript it will create mess for you.So to avoid it and use two validation one using javascript and one in php to save yourself from crisis.What you think?

Comment: Yes, you can also use `<noscript>...</noscript>` for people not using JS. I believe that's still a valid tag.

Comment: you can use `!empty()` and `isset()` in PHP in conjunction with ajax, that's what I meant by "getting the best of both worlds". That way you get validation for both js/php and will work even if js is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in but 3rd-party library provided on NPM.

https://github.com/mpyw/FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL.js